# rand function generates 5 digit number, how can I make it generate 11 digit number

Tags: php, random

I have a table named "message_group" and this table includes "user_one, user_two and hash" fields. Hash is int(11). With the following piece of code I insert values into this table. I am using the `rand()` function. My problem is that this function inserts only a 5 digit number into the fiels of hash in my table. I want this number to be of 11 digits. How can I modify my code to achieve that?

```
if( isset($_POST['message']) && !empty($_POST['message'])  ){
    $random_number = rand();

    $check_con = mysql_query("SELECT `hash` FROM `message_group` WHERE (`user_one`='$session_user_id' AND `user_two`='$user_id') OR (`user_one`='$user_id' AND `user_two`='$session_user_id')");

    if( mysql_num_rows($check_con) == 1 ){
        echo"conversation already started";
    }else{
        mysql_query(" INSERT INTO message_group VALUES ('$session_user_id', '$user_id', '$random_number') ");
        echo"conversation started";
    }
}
```

Comment: How uniformly distributed do you need the result to be?

Comment: I just want to generate an 11 digit number, and if it is possible to be unique each time

Comment: The duplicate shows how to make an 11 digit number. It will obviously not be unique every time, so you'll have to check that it's not yet in the database.

Comment: you are right...any idea how to make it generate a unique 11 digit number each time?

Comment: By the way, `isset($_POST['message']) && !empty($_POST['message'])` is superfluous. `!empty($_POST['message'])` does the same thing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+unique+random+number

Comment: Hash !== random number. What do you want to use this for? `rand` is not a very good source of randomness for most purposes.

Comment: I want to use hash as an ID to another table

Comment: Why does it need to be random then and not a regular `AUTO_INCREMENT` id? And if you want non-sequential ids, UUIDs are the typical choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP's `rand()` is only 15 bits on some platforms. You can increase it to 30 bits by using:

```
((rand() << 15) ^ rand())
```

This will give you a number in the range 0..1073741823, still evenly distributed. If you need something more specific than just a bigger range, you'll have to do some fancier math after that. You might also consider mt_rand().

Answer (score 1):

From [PHP rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)

> Note: On some platforms (such as Windows), getrandmax() is only 32767.
>   If you require a range larger than 32767, specifying min and max will
>   allow you to create a range larger than this, or consider using
>   mt_rand() instead.

Therefore, dont use default values and specifi min and max

```
int rand ( int $min , int $max )
```

Answer (score 0):

a uniformly distributed random number with arbitrary number of digits can be generated from a 16 bit RNG by repeated multiply-and-add. Example ( pseudo code):

```
ans=0;
mult = MAXRAND+1;
for(i=0;i<5;i++) ans=mult*ans+rand();
```

As long as `ans` can hold the result, you can make any size uniformly distributed random number this way. Obviously you want to make sure you handle overflow, and limit the number of digits at the end.